# R Problems with installing tidyverse on linux

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the tidyverse-package on Linux, but there appears the following error message:

What can I do to solve this problem?

My system runs under Fedora 31.

I couldn't find similar solutions.

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
Installing package into ‘/home/tobias/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 158465 bytes (154 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 154 KB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rvest_0.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1129355 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 696 KB

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'httr' ...
** package 'httr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'httr'
    finding HTML links ... done
    BROWSE                                  html  
    DELETE                                  html  
    GET                                     html  
    HEAD                                    html  
    PATCH                                   html  
    POST                                    html  
    PUT                                     html  
    RETRY                                   html  
    Token-class                             html  
    VERB                                    html  
    add_headers                             html  
    authenticate                            html  
    cache_info                              html  
    config                                  html  
    content                                 html  
Error: error reading from connection
* removing '/home/tobias/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/httr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependency 'httr' is not available for package 'rvest'
* removing '/home/tobias/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rvest'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
ERROR: dependencies 'httr', 'rvest' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing '/home/tobias/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tidyverse'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI7rbRK/downloaded_packages’
```

Here is my session-info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 31 (KDE Plasma)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2
```

What can I do to install the tidyverse-package?

And what does it mean: "installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status"?

Comment: Are [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) and [openssl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openssl/index.html) already installed? Just asking cause these are the two package imported by `httr`  and that have specific system requirements.

Comment: yes they are installed

Comment: "installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status" simply means the installation fails. I must say the error message does not make it easy to understand why  it fails... I am not familiar with fedora, looks like everything is ok for Fedora 30 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_httr.html), not sure this is helpful though.